# React-cookie: Invariant Violation: The root route must render a single element

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-cookie

I'm using [react-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie) package, when I try to set it up at the highest level component, it will throw me these errors:

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol.
>
> Invariant Violation: The root route must render a single element

```
[1] Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: symbol.
[1]     in RouterContext
[1]     in AsyncConnect
[1]     in Connect(AsyncConnect)
[1]     in IntlProvider
[1]     in Connect(IntlProvider)
[1]     in Provider
[1]     in Context.Provider
[1]     in CookiesProvider
[1]     in StyleSheetManager
[1] C:\Users\me\Projects\my-application\node_modules\react-transform-catch-errors\lib\index.js:47
[1]             throw err;
[1]             ^
[1] Invariant Violation: The root route must render a single element
[1]     at invariant (C:\Users\me\Projects\my-application\node_modules\invariant\invariant.js:40:15)
[1]     at Object.render (C:\Users\me\Projects\my-application\node_modules\react-router\lib\RouterContext.js:125:155)
[1]     at processChild (C:\Users\me\Projects\htmmy-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2959:18)
[1]     at resolve (C:\Users\me\Projects\my-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2812:5)
    at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render (C:\Users\me\Projects\my-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3202:22)
[1]     at ReactDOMServerRenderer.read (C:\Users\me\Projects\my-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3161:29)
[1]     at Object.renderToString (C:\Users\me\Projects\my-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:3646:27)
[1]     at Html.render (C:/Users/me/Projects/my-application/src/helpers/Html.js:29:42)
[1]     at Html.tryRender (C:\Users\me\Projects\my-application\node_modules\react-transform-catch-errors\lib\index.js:34:31)
[1]     at processChild (C:\Users\me\Projects\my-application\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server.node.development.js:2959:18)
```

// Routes

```
export default () => (
  <Route path="/:locale/" component={App}>
    ...
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
  </Route>
);
```

// LoginPage (Putting like this doesn't work)

```
@withCookies
@connect(state => ({ auth: state.auth }), { login })
export default class LoginPage extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    cookies: PropTypes.instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }
  ...
```

---

However, if I move it into another component and import it, it will work.

// LoginPage

```
export default class LoginPage extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Login />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

// Login

```
@withCookies
@connect(state => ({ auth: state.auth }), { login })
export default class Login extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    cookies: PropTypes.instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }
  ...
```

---

I have tried exporting in different ways but still got the same error:

```
export class LoginPage extends PureComponent {
  ...
}

const App = connect(state => ({ auth: state.auth }), { login })(LoginPage);

export default withCookies(App);
```

Is there a way I can set up in the highest level component?

---

Additional info:

// server.js

```
    const component = (
      <CookiesProvider cookies={req.universalCookies}>
        <Provider store={store} key="provider">
          <IntlProvider>
            <ReduxAsyncConnect {...renderProps} />
          </IntlProvider>
        </Provider>
      </CookiesProvider>
    );

    const html = ReactDOM.renderToString(
      <Html assets={webpackIsomorphicTools.assets()} component={component} store={store} />
    );
    res.status(200);
    res.send(`<!doctype html>\n${html}`);
```

Comment: Have you tried without using decorator ?

Comment: @GaëlS you mean `export default withCookies(connect(state => ({ auth: state.auth }), { login })(LoginPage))`?

Comment: yes with the HOC form

Comment: @GaëlS Yeap, I have tried `export default withCookies(connect(state => ({ auth: state.auth }), { login })(LoginPage))` and it throws the same error

Comment: Could you show the file where you call `ReactDOM.render` ?

Comment: @GaëlS sure! I've updated on the question

Answer (score 0):

Following `react-cookies` server side, the code from the example is like this:

```
// src/server.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { CookiesProvider } from 'react-cookie';

import Html from './components/Html';
import App from './components/App';

export default function middleware(req, res) {
  const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <CookiesProvider cookies={req.universalCookies}>
      <App />
    </CookiesProvider>
  );

  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<Html markup={markup} />);

  res.send('<!DOCTYPE html>' + html);
}
```

Don't know if it's related but you do not use `ReactDOMServer` but `ReactDOM`, is there a reason ?

Comment: Sorry I should have included my imports, it is the react-dom/server: `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/server';` I have tried the suggestion (removing other providers and left with just `<ReduxAsyncConnect {...renderProps} />` but still not working